# getResourceStream for writing files

Tags: java, java-me, getresource

For javame.

Since `getResourceAsStream()` is for reading files, is there a `getResourceAsStream()` equivalent for output stream / writing files?

Note: the file is inside the project's folders and will soon be packaged into a jarfile.

Comment: I already answered this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058435/how-to-write-to-an-xml-file-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getResoureAsStream() deals with resources. Returning an output stream doesn't make sense because that implies you are trying to overwrite your resources on the fly.

Besides, for most resources residing in a JAR or remote locations, you can't write to it anyway.

Comment: What I want to do is to overwrite a file inside a jar. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You can't overwrite a file inside a jar. To replace anything,  you have to create a new jar.

Comment: You could write the file to a db if you wan't to dynamically load images into your app

Answer (score 1):

It would not make sense to have that.
What would the getResourceAsStream get, since the resource does not exist yet?

In addition getResourceAsStream is typically used to access a file within a JAR or WAR, you cannot write there.

getResourceAsStream is typically used to load configuration and properties files.
[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) (a little dated) on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's why I'm wondering if there's an equivalent to that... something like setResourceAsStream? IDK. I need to write to the xml file inside a jar.

Comment: @cancelledout No can do - Look at the many posts and you will see that you cannot  modify or delete a jar unless you create a new one and overwrite the old one. You will need to pick another destination. I already answered this question for you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058435/how-to-write-to-an-xml-file-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
create a [File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)-Object and then call getOutputStream on this file object.

Comment: The FileConnection class doesn't recognize a path of a file inside the project's folder or jar. =X

Answer (score 0):

FileOutputStream is also available for java me.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
out.write( ... );
```

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get back to the office. Thanks for your reply. :D